# How to show embedded video inside Html widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show a video inside the data. Here is the api :

```
https://wrestlingworld.co/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=22
```

If you run this you will be able to see video link inside content -> rendred. I want to show the video inside Html widget I don't know its possible to show the video inside Html widget.

Here what I tried:

```
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Html(
              data: newsDetails.content!.rendered!,
              style: {
                "body": Style(
                    fontSize: const FontSize(16),
                    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans'),
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

In my code I successfully showed the data but can't show the video. Its coming like this image I attached:

[image]

So How can I show the video inside Html widget or Is there any other solution for this?